# Extract and Apply, Using Apply to set NAs to 0 or revert to NA conditions unmet.

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I'm playing around with my test dataset, trying to mirror real-world problems or tasks that I encounter with data.

Currently, I'm attempting to set NAs to 0 across multiple variables(columns) that I've extracted from a larger dataset, which i'll then sum, and if the result is zero, revert the columns back to NA. Below is my line of thinking/way I've attempted to do this on my own, but if any of you can think of a preferred or easier to read way I'd love to see it!

Here's what I've come up with, so far.

```
#Play Data
v1 <- c("Blue","Red","Blue","Red","Purple")
v2 <- c(1,NA,3,4,NA)
v3 <- c(NA,NA,3,4,5)
v4 <- c(1,NA,1,2,2)
v5 <- c(1,NA,3,NA,5)

x = data.frame (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
```

I'm extracting the columns that I'll need for this operation and using sapply to determine NAs.

```
Extract<- sapply(x[,c("v2","v3","v4","v5")], is.na)
```

Followed by a custom function (That I've recycled from other previous operations). Which is where my error crops up...

```
x[Extract] <- lapply(x[Extract], function(k) replace(k, is.na(k), 0))

# I get the below error
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Extract, value = list("Red", "Purple",  : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

I've given different kinds of apply functions a shot, to no avail. But, i'm almost positive therein lies my problems. If I were to continue my script and complete the aforementioned task, my next two lines of code would be...

```
x$vcheck <- rowSums(x[, c("v2","v3","v4","v5")], na.rm=TRUE)
x[x$vcheck == 0, c("v2","v3","v4","v5")] <- NA # For rows without any values
```

Hopefully, together, this script would take rows where a number/answer is present and put 0s in place of any NAs in that row. However, if there are no numbers/answers in the row then it will convert the row back to all NAs.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or think of a better way I'd appreciate it.

Thanks again all!

Comment: Your indexing is messed up. Why not just `x[is.na(x)] <- 0`? Or make that your starting point, at least.

Comment: @alistaire I could be overthinking it, which is a frequent issue.  I will adjust the first part of that code `b <- x[, c("v2","v3","v4","v5")]` followed by 
`b[is.na(b)] <- 0`. But, I actually think that could solve the problem overall once I determine how to reintroduce it into the main dataset

Comment: In the data here, at least, including the first column isn't going to change anything, since it doesn't have any `NA`s. If that's a possibility, an easier way of indexing is using negative integer positions to exclude the column: `x[, -1]`

Comment: That is a strange "real-world problem". `NA` is not zero and shouldn't be set to zero.

Comment: @alistaire Generally the real dataset would be a fair amount larger, I've been using the names here just for consistency's sake.

Comment: @Roland When my data is delivered it generally has a large amount of blanks - online survey data, which R converts directly to NAs. This is fine in the vast majority of circumstances indicative of a skipped item or someone who did not continue; however, in this example, simplistically, i'm attempting to distinguish those who saw the item and responded to one of the items in the series (One item will/should apply to all), versus those who skipped the entire series or did not see the question.   Leaving all NA could potentially inflate a denominator.

Comment: Actually, that sounds like exactly the case in which you want `NA`. It's probably better to use `na.rm = TRUE` if it's a parameter or `na.omit` if it's not so everything will get counted properly. For example, if you try to calculate `sd` (or anything that uses it) after inserting zeros for missing data, your results will be considerably skewed.